# Prove that if $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ divides $h(x)$, then $f(x)$ divides $s(x)g(x) +t(x)h(x)$.

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

Let $F$ be a field. Prove that for all polynomials $f(x), g(x), h(x) \in {F}[x]$, if $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ divides $h(x)$, then for all polynomials $s(x), t(x)\in {F}[x]$, $f(x)$ divides $s(x)g(x) +t(x)h(x)$.

How do I prove this question? I know that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ but I'm not sure if I use that at all in this question.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a factor of both $g(x)$ and $h(x)$. Consider the case where $f(x)=2$, $g(x)=4$, and $h(x)=20$. Does $f(x)$ divide $4\cdot s + 20 \cdot t$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** How would you prove an equivalent statment for the integers?

Comment: Would I use DIC for polynomials?

Comment: What is DIC?...

Comment: If a divides b and a divides c then for integers x,y a divides bx+cy

Comment: Actualy this is an equivalent statement, you need to remember how do you prove it.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$, then $g(x) = f(x)q(x)$ and likewise $h(x) = f(x)r(x)$.

Also note that $f(x)$ divides $s(x)g(x)$, since $s(x)g(x) = s(x) f(x)q(x)$.